Quickest way to see sql queries that have modified a specific row in Postgres
I'm trying to find a way to see what queries ran in the past have modified the data of a row.
For example say you have a table like this:
users table



id
name
email




1
Bill
bill@domain.com



Let's say this query was ran at some point (from code or raw query or from anywhere).
UPDATE users SET email='john@domain.com' WHERE id = 1
And then another query was ran at some point after that 1st query.
UPDATE users SET email='susan@domain.com' WHERE email='john@domain.com'
I want to somehow see a history of all the queries that had an effect on that specific row, ordered by most recent queries.
Is there a way to do that by default without any additional extensions or triggers? I tried some of those approaches but they seem to bloated for something that should have a standard way?
